# What permissions are required to allow attaching a remote performance monitor?

Tags: security, permissions, windows-server, performance-monitor

I am attempting to monitor a few metrics on a domain database server (Win 2008 R2) but receiving unable to connect message when attempting to connect with the built-in Performance Monitor (Windows 7 Enterprise).

What permissions are required to allow this?  Would prefer not to grant log on locally or any type of interactive permissions.

Comment: dangit; meant to ask this on serverfault.

Comment: How are you attempting to connect?  Just opening an ETL file from the server?

Comment: windows performance monitor, click add button, enter server name.

Comment: So you're trying to connect the Performance Monitor, not the Performance Analyzer, right?  What is the exact error it's giving you?

Comment: "Unable to connect to machine".  I am connected to it via SQL Server Management Studio, so it's definitely live.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

- If the server has the Windows firewall up, then ensure an exception for the Performance Logs and Alerts is enabled.
- Your user needs to belong to the Performance Log Users, Performance Monitor Users group and the Event Log Readers group on the server (or domain).
- Ensure the Remote Registry service is running on the server.

I think that'll do it.

Comment: Does the user also need to be a member of the default Users group? Or can that be omitted?

Comment: Still getting error,
Source - Windows 10 
Destination - Windows 2012 server
Getting parameter incorrect error